# Trouble plotting Niger only without Nigeria r maps

Tags: r, maps, country-codes

I am trying to fill in the country of Niger in map() in the maps package. I realize that specific countries that begin with certain letters will all plot unless you specify, but I cannot get it to plot only Niger without plotting Nigeria.

```
library(maps)
#plot map of Africa
map(database = "world", regions = ".", xlim = c(-20,60), ylim = c(-40,40), wrap = FALSE, resolution = 2, type = "l", bg = par("bg"), myborder = 0.01)

# fills in Nigeria alone
map(regions = 'Nigeria',fill = TRUE, add = TRUE, col = 'green')

#fills in the countries of Niger AND Nigeria
map(regions = 'Niger',fill = TRUE, add = TRUE, col = 'gray')
```

After reading the 'maps' documentation and finding [this question](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Maps-Country-coding-td2067695.html) I looked in the `countrycode_data` list of countries from the 'countrycode' package I found the regex `\\bniger(?!ia)` which I believe is part of my problem. I have the same problem with any other countries that start with the same letters or words such as "Guinea," "Papua New Guinea," and "Guinea-Bissau." How can I plot only the simplest version country name? None of the codes from package countrycode plot Niger alone on the map either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the `map()` description in the *maps* library [manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/maps/maps.pdf) :

> exact : If TRUE , only exact matches with regions are selected for
>   drawing. If FALSE , each element of regions is matched as a regular
>   expression against the polygon names in the database and all matches
>   are selected for drawing.

all that is needed is to set `exact=TRUE` in:

```
map(regions = 'Niger', exact=TRUE, fill = TRUE, add = TRUE, col = 'gray')
```

which produces the desired result

[image]